# Употребление предлогов

Tags: стилистика

Просьба помочь вот по какому вопросу.

Как правильно писать:

Привести в соответствие с чем или чему?

Направить в адрес или по адресу?

Направляем в подтверждение или для подтверждения?

Просьба на Грамоту.ру не ссылаться, у них разнобой в ответах.
Просьба также не растекаться мысию по древу, а дать чёткий ответ с соответствующими ссылками на пособия.

С уважением ко всем,
Татьяна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Устойчивое выражение: "привести в соответствие что-н. с чем-н. "Методические разработки привели в соответствие с учебными планами". (Из Словаря грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка" (РАН, серия "Словари 21 века", 2013 г.).

2) Предлоги В, ДЛЯ, ПО имеют следующее обобщенное значение: В - действие направлено на объект, ДЛЯ – действие совершается относительно границ объекта, ПО – действие направлено в соответствии с объектом.

3) Направить по адресу (в соответствии с адресом) – указывается конкретный адрес, по которому расположен адресат. Направить в адрес – направить непосредственно адресату (направление на объект).

Примеры: Для участия необходимо направить в адрес дирекции (в электронном виде или по факсу) предварительную заявку. Официальный запрос представители СМИ могут направить по адресу: ул. Новокузнецкая, д. 27.

4) (1) Направляем в подтверждение (в доказательство истинности). (2) Направьте для подтверждения  (для установления истинности).  Реже здесь используется форма (1)
Адресант не сомневается в истинности (он ее доказывает адресату), а адресату нужно установление или доказательство истинности.

Примеры: В подтверждение нашей договоренности высылаем Вам… Для подтверждения ставки НДС необходимо предоставить …

Comment: София, большое спасибо!

Правильно ли я поняла, что, например, направить в Минюст - это  конкретному лицу или подразделению, а в адрес Минюста - это безотносительно, кому или в какое подразделение?

Comment: Думаю, что надо различать такие варианты: (1)"Транснефть" направила письмо в адрес Минюста или в Минюст (это одно и то же, первая формулировка отражает деловой стиль). (2) Сведения необходимо направлять в Главное управление Министерства юстиции РФ по Москве по адресу: 117997,Москва, ул. Кржижановского, дом 13.

Comment: София, извините, задала этот вопрос вторично по ошибке, хотя Вы всё разъяснили.

Скажите, а все вышесказанное по четырем пунктам почерпнуто из Словаря грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка" (РАН, серия "Словари 21 века", 2013 г.)?

Comment: Нет, только п.1., глагола "направить" там нет, он, наверное, не считается сложным. Значение предлогов указаны в Грамматике-80, остальное - применение этих сведений на практике.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Если вы живете в Москве, готова встретиться и вручить букет в знак благодарности.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за добрые слова, мне всегда интересно Ваш мнение.

Comment: София, просмотрела Грамматику-80, но нашла только это.

В соответствии с чем-н., соответственно с чем-н. - определение по соответствию, по примененности к чему-н.: действовать в соответствии/соответст-венно с обстановкой, с требованиями момента. Поведение - в соответствии/ соответственно с ситуацией, с обстоятельствами.


А конкретно по структуре   
привести в соответствие (чему?) или (с чем?) так и не нашла.

Ужас какой-то.

Comment: Это ссылка на словарь, где дается ответ.  http://slovari21.ru/catalog/publications/slovar_grammaticheskoy_sochetaemosti_slov_russkogo_yazika

Там для слова "соответствие" даются 4 формы и устойчивое сочетание: 1) кого-чего кому-чему; 2) кого-чего; 3) между кем/чем и кем/чем; 4) между кем/чем; 5) Устойчивое выражение: привести в соответствие что-н. с чем-н. Чисто на слух именно это выражение кажется правильным, можно заменить: согласовать что-н. с чем-н.

Comment: София, словарь не открывается. Только обложка. Не могли бы дать ссылку на тот адрес с которого вы заходили.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Привести в соответствие ***чему***. Напр.: Привести в соответствие (во что), привести документацию (во что?) в соответствие (чему?) требованиям заказчика.
Но: в соответствии (с чем) (соответственно, согласно чему-н.). Провести испытания (как?) в соответствии (с чем?) с требованиями заказчика.

См. Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук. Под редакцией Лопатина. 
Грамота.ру абсолютно права.

***См. вопрос-ответ. 

Помогите пожалуйста найти истину.

Мой документ подвергается критике разными службами - одни правят на -ИИ, другие - наоборот, на -ИЕ.

Первоначально текст у меня такой:

"Цель исследования - перепись ... в соответствии с настоящей методологией ..."***

***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

Правильно: ***находиться в соответствии, привести в соответствие, действовать в соответствии с чем-либо.***
Вопрос 2. [Конструкции в адрес - по адресу](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_78)
Направляем в подтверждение ***(В подтверждение, в зн. нареч.



Для того, чтобы подтвердить какую-л. мысль, какие-л. слова. Предъявить документы в подтверждение своих слов. В подтверждение того, что, в зн. союза.

Присоединяет придаточную часть предложения, в которой подтверждается что-л. В подтверждение того, что он приехал, была послана телеграмма).***

Для подтверждения - для того, чтобы кто-то что-то подтвердил ***(предлог для*** указывает на лицо, которому что-л. предназначается). ***(Толковый словарь под Редакцией Кузнецова).***

***Дополнение***

***Ответ Граммы.ру***

Устойчивое сочетание "привести в соответствие" имеет варианты управления: чему-л. и с чем-л. Предложное управление - явление несколько более новое, однако современной норме оно вполне соответствует.

***Ответ справочной службы русского языка(Грамота.ру)***

1. Верно: привести в соответствие чему-либо и (согласно рекомендациям ряда справочников) с чем-либо.

Comment: Серж, спасибо, но Грамота дает ответы взаимоисключающие, поэтому я и прсила не ссылаться на неё.
Окончание в слове "соответствие" меня абсолютно не интересует. Только управление.

Comment: Татьяна, я задал вопрос Грамоте.ру. Посмотрим, что-они ответят. Я спрошу еще у Граммы.ру. Я просмотрел также ответы Грамоты. Но везде нашел один ответ: соответствие чему-то.

Comment: Серж, в словаре сочетаемости приводится вариант "соответствие КОГО-ЧЕГО КОМУ-ЧЕМУ, то есть Р.п. - Д.п. "Он стал проверять соответствие содержания законов основным правовым принципам, закреплённым в конституции". Сравнить: "Необходимо этот принцип привести в соответствие с этическими требованиями общества" (Т.п.)

Comment: Друзья!  
Еще один вопрос.  
Как все-таки следует писать:  

Направить письмо в Минюст или в адрес Минюста.

Думаю, что это равнозначно. Но хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.

Comment: Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильно: находиться в соответствии, привести в соответствие, действовать в соответствии с чем-либо.

Вот и пойми из этого, как писать:

привести локальные нормативные акты в соответствие отраслевым нормативным актам или в соответствие с отраслевыми нормативными актами?

Из ответа Софии я поняла, что второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: Грамота.ру как раз советует дательный падеж. (Во всех ответах). Но в словарях встречается и творительных падеж. Со остальными глаголами проблем нет - только творительных падеж.

Comment: София, вы говорите дательный.пад. А в ответе вы приводите творительный пад. Так какой же там вариант?

Comment: Серж, у меня бумажная книга, вы сами поищите ее в Сети. Я считаю правильными следующие варианты: обеспечить соответствие документов законодательству (Р.п. - Д.п.), привести документы  в соответствие с законодательством (Т.п.).